# Error 'The operation has timed out' when calling Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

We are using `Invoke-WebRequest` in a number of PowerShell scripts that run in sequence over a period of about 10 minutes.

We are trying to understand why, in some rare cases, a `System.Net.WebException` is thrown with the message:

> The operation has timed out

Reading the article [Understanding MaxServicePointIdleTime and DefaultConnectionLimit](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2009/05/20/understanding-maxservicepointidletime-and-defaultconnectionlimit/) does indicate that the timeout is due reaching the connection limit. Increasing the connection limit does not seem like the way to fix the root cause of the issue.

This makes us think that our scripts are not disposing all of their resources once they are finished. What is the recommended way of using `Invoke-WebRequest` that disposes all resources?

We are currently doing;

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri_1 -ContentType $mime
// do stuff with $response variable

$response = Invoke-WebRequest -uri $uri_2 -ContentType $mime    
// do stuff with $response variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `$response | get-member` you can see that the `HtmlWebResponseObject` object has a `Dispose` Method, so you should be able to dispose of the connection by doing:

```
$response.Dispose()
```

after you have finished with it.

Comment: That is interesting. One follow-up question, the current scripts make at least 50 invoke-webrequest and like I mention in the original post, it rarely fail. Does Powershell or dotnet perform any sort of cleanup of the tcp connections and what triggers this cleanup? Starting to wonder why this is not failing more often.